# Vuetify make all buttons rounded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify application with too many buttons, i want to change them all with rounded style but without having to add this property one by one. 
Is there any way using themes or presets to add this feature?

Adding style like bellow works:

```
  .v-btn{
        border-radius:28px!important;
    }
```

but in this way i use the ability to use normal buttons forever.

Creating a custom component like `my-rounded-button` also works. But imagine you want to set properties globally for other components, This way you have to create a custom component for every element in vuetify. Not to mention if you want to change all buttons in the middle of the project, you still have to change all the button names from `v-btn` to `my-rounded-button`.

What i am looking for is to make rounded property set to true for all `v-btn`components, then whenever i want to use not rounded i still have the option by setting it to `:rounded="false"`.

Comment: Why not use CSS?

Comment: override the base css class for the button with the style you want

Comment: @connexo What if i want to add other properties to a vuetify element globally? in bootstrap we could add this too all buttons globally. There has to be a way in vuetify as well

Comment: Just create a custom component that uses the vuetify button.

Comment: As @HusamIbrahim said try to create custom component by extending the base component by adding the `rounded` prop

Comment: @HusamIbrahim This way i still have to change all button names. there are like 500 of them, imagine this: With this solution for every element in Vuetify i have to create a custom component at the beginning of project, then i can add custom properties globally every time i want to. It doesn't make any scenes .

Answer (score 2):

After trying to find a way to define a default prop using [`presets`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/presets) but this doesn't work with all components like buttons, so i suggest to define the global CSS rule :

```
 .v-btn{
    border-radius:28px!important;
 }
```

and when you want to use a normal button add another CSS rule like :

```
 .v-btn-not-rounded{
    border-radius:4px!important;
 }
```

and use class binding as follows :

```
  <v-btn depressed :class={'v-btn-not-rounded':true} color="primary">not rounded</v-btn>
```

check this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/jOPVJwz)

Comment: What about scss? I found out that we have variable $btn-border-radius that has default value of 6px, we can change it to 28px and it changes, then i can change another variable $btn-rounded-border-radius with default value of 28px to 6px, now whenever i want to change it to normal i can use rounded. But still this is very annoying, we have other props like outline that have many styles, with no scss variable...

Comment: Yes it's annoying this not enough flexible